# How to change windows form skin in c# program.

Tags: c#

How to change windows form skin in c# program. How to use dll files for that. From where I find dll file for change skin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stardock used to provide a component as part of their WindowBlinds product that could do this.  I don't know if they still do.